# Check if bluetooth is enabled or not

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I've some trouble on checking with flutter if bluetooth is ON or OFF on Android or iOs.
I've tried this code but nothing happen when this page is loaded.

this is an adaptation from the package flutte_blue_plus code.

Here on stackoverflow i can only found old code (with no sound null safety).

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';
import 'package:qbit/routes/index_routes.dart';

//Check if is ON
class BleEnabled extends StatefulWidget {
  const BleEnabled({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<BleEnabled> createState() => BleEnabledState();
}

class BleEnabledState extends State<BleEnabled> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkBLE();
  }

  void checkBLE() async {
    StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
      stream: FlutterBluePlus.instance.state,
      initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
      builder: (c, snapshot) {
        final state = snapshot.data;
        if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
          debugPrint('bluetooth state ON');
          return const ChangePage();
        }
        debugPrint('bluetooth state OFF');
        return AskTurnOnBLE();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChangePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChangePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  ChangePageState createState() => ChangePageState();
}

class ChangePageState extends State<ChangePage> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.connection);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class AskTurnOnBLE extends StatefulWidget {
  const AskTurnOnBLE({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  AskTurnOnBLEState createState() => AskTurnOnBLEState();
}

class AskTurnOnBLEState extends State<AskTurnOnBLE> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool openedSettings = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
    showMessage();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void showMessage() async {
    Get.dialog(
      AlertDialog(
        content: Column(children: [
          //.....
          //.....
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              openedSettings = true;
              AppSettings.openBluetoothSettings();
              Get.back();
            },
            child: Text('Open Settings'),
          ),
        ]),
        actions: [],
      ),
      barrierDismissible: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        if (openedSettings) {
          BleEnabled();
        }
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        debugPrint('App inactive');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        openedSettings = true;
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        debugPrint('App detached');
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: StreamBuilder is meant to build a Widget as part of the build() method, now you are creating it from checkBLE so it will never do anything.

Comment: see this maybe work [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257531/flutter-app-needs-to-check-if-bluetooth-and-location-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this package [bluetooth_enable](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_enable)

or try this

```
Future<bool> _checkDeviceBluetoothIsOn() async { 
   return await FlutterBluePlus.isOn; 
 }
```

Comment: The package Bluetooth_enabled isn't null safety, I've tried Bluetooth_enable_fork (that is null safety) but it doesn't work. I've found flutter_blue_elves and it's example work good